# grails g:uploadForm how to detect upload completion by GSP

Tags: grails

When using a g:uploadForm, is there anyway to detect that the file upload has been completed by javascript? I want to use this as an event to show a modal dialog that shows information about the uploaded file.

It is easy to detect by the controller because that is simply when the upload function finishes execution but how can I make my GSP detect this and therefore react.

Comment: Are you posting the file to an iframe?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Yes. As per your advice in another post. That has worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting to/targeting an `iframe` for your form submission it should be easy enough for your `controller` that accepts the upload to render some `jquery` to the `iframe` to notify the parent window that the upload is complete. In this example I will use a custom `jquery` event.

Containing GSP:

```
$(document).on("upload-complete", function(e) {
  console.log("Upload completed.");
});
```

GSP template rendered by the controller within the iframe:

```
parent.$(document).trigger({
  type: 'upload-complete'
});
```

The above `jquery` should accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: I put your first bit of code in the script portion of my GSP and then I put the second bit in my controller's render clause like this: render { div(id: "framediv",
        '<script>parent.$(document).trigger({type: "upload-complete"});</script>')} where "framediv" is the parent div of the iframe. I see no errors but I also do not see the console.log printed. Note, I exchanged your single and double quotes because I had trouble escaping the '$' before (document) during compilation.

Comment: I'd avoid using a render like that and use a template. _upload.gsp in the views directory for said controller and render(template: 'upload'). That way you can embed the jquery as you would normally on any GSP/html page.

Comment: I had actually intended to follow your directions exactly but I ran into where I wasn't sure how to specify that I want the template rendered in the iframe. So I tried to use the type of render you advised against because I saw you can pick the div you want rendered into with it. When you put javascript in a template does it need to be wrapped in <script></script> tags?

Comment: Yes it does need to be wrapped in script tags, and given this is jquery it needs to be wrapped inside the typical jquery document ready code as well. Sorry, I just assumed you would pick up on those facts.

Comment: Please....don't be sorry. Thanks for all the free advice rather. How about specifying that i want the template rendered in the iframe?

Comment: Ok. I did all of the above and keep getting this in the Chrome debugger:  ReferenceError: $ is not defined . I get this whether I do it the _upload.gsp render template way or whether I render the raw javascript straight from the controller. And if I replace the $ with the good old document.getElementbyID that turns out to be null. But if I simply tell render the javascript from the controller to put up a modal that says "hi", it works. So something is definitely happening from the controller to the GSP but not the desired effect.

Comment: Are you not including jquery in the template being rendered? Remember, it's inside an iframe and is no different than a new window/tab. Given the error you are getting then I suspect that's the issue.

Comment: Ok I got no errors in Chrome debugger but no desired results(meaning no "upload completed" printed in chrome debugger). Here's my _upload.gsp:<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<r:layoutResources/>
 
<script type="text/javascript">

$("document").ready(function() {
  $('document').trigger({
    type: 'upload-complete'
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ok an update. I can log stuff to the console from within the template but it won't do the parent.trigger. I think part of it might be that I am just flat rendering this template but I still don't see how I am rendering it in the iframe. I have not specified this anywhere. The word "parent" is missing from my code in the previous comment but I put it in since commenting and that hasn't changed the behaviour. You assumed corretnly that jQuery inclusion was my previous issue. Im starting to feel like a help Vampire :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [**Ajax Uploader plugin**](http://grails.org/plugin/ajax-uploader).

This is what you would need

```
<uploader:uploader id="yourUploaderId" 
                   url="${[controller:'yourController', action:'yourAction']}" />
```

There are callbacks associated:

```
<uploader:onSubmit>
<uploader:onProgress>
<uploader:onComplete>
<uploader:onCancel>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a great plugin, exactly what I need. Unfortunately I think I am still too dumb at this point to use it. I tried following its requirements and I cannot seem to figure out in any combination/mutation of how to properly use the <r:require> and <r:layoutResources>. I keep getting errors regarding how I use these two tags in my GSP.